# _CastError (type 'Client' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>' in type cast)

Tags: json, flutter, dart, model

My API returns the following response:

```
[{id: 1, nome: foo}, {id: 2, nome: bar}]
```

And I created a model `Client` to represent each one:

```
class Client {
  final int id;
  final String name;

  Client({
    this.id,
    this.name,
  });

  factory Client.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Client(
      id: json['id'],
      name: json['nome'],
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'id': id,
        'nome': name,
      };
}
```

Then, in my repository, the method fetching the data above is as follows:

```
Future<List<Client>> getClients() async {
  try {
    final _response = await _dio.get(
      '/clientes',
      options: Options(
        headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer $TOKEN'},
      ),
    );

    return Client.fromJson(_response.data[0]) as List; // Error pointed to this line
  } on DioError catch (_e) {
    throw _e;
  }
}
```

Being stored here

```
@observable
List<Client> clients;
```

I am not sure what to do. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dio` will decode the response and you'll get a `List<dynamic>`. Use `List.map` to convert it to a list of clients, by passing a function that will turn a `Map<String, dynamic>` into a `Client`. (You already have one - the named constructor.)

For example:

```
  var dioResponse = json.decode('[{"id": 1, "nome": "foo"}, {"id": 2, "nome": "bar"}]');

  List<dynamic> decoded = dioResponse;
  var clients = decoded.map<Client>((e) => Client.fromJson(e)).toList();
```

Comment: It's throwing an error pointing to `json.decode` saying `_type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<List<Client>>'`

Comment: Ok, it seems it is partially solved. The error is now `type 'List<void>' is not a subtype of type 'List<DropdownMenuItem<Client>>`

Comment: you don't show any code that could be creating that

Comment: Yes I'm aware. Haven't put any since the first issue was making it reach the view.

Comment: Since that part is solved I will mark yours as the correct one. This is a different issue now.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to cast a `Client` as a `List<dynamic>` which isn't a valid cast since `Client` doesn't implement `List`. If you want to return a `List` containing a single `Client`, you'll want to change the line with the error to:

```dart
return [Client.fromJson(_response.data[0])];
```

Comment: I don't want only one but the whole response at once. I did a `for` loop, adding each `Client` into the new variable type `Client` and then returning the `List<Client>`. Now, I face `type 'MappedListIterable<Client, void>' is not a subtype of type 'List<DropdownMenuItem<Client>>'`

Comment: `.toList()` will turn an iterable into a list. Looks like you then need a further `map` to turn the clients into dropdown menu items.

Comment: Ah, that's not what your code was doing there though. It was simply trying to cast a single `Client` as a `List`.